# Using soft keyboard on libgdx for iOS and Android (hides textview)

Tags: height, libgdx, hide, soft-keyboard, obscured-view

Does anyone have experience in making games that use the soft keyboard for libgdx apps on both Android and iOS.

I am able to bring up the soft keyboard on my Android device, but it hides the textview I want to edit. This leads me to the need of getting the soft keyboard height in pixels so I can rescale the UI. I have tried to search for how to do this all over the place without reading any posts that actually seems to solve it well. Does anyone know if soft keyboards work well in libgdx on both iOS and Android and how to avoid obscuring textviews?

Answer (score 0):

See this thread for a workaround using native text-input dialogs:

[How do libgdx detect keyboard presence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604963/how-do-libgdx-detect-keyboard-presence/23036055#23036055)