# How to use a SQLite database with LibGDX application [android]

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, libgdx

I am developing a game for Android using LibGDX and a key requirement of this project is to be able to store and query data in a database. I need a database for several reasons; one main reason being the need to store user details when they sign up and validate them when they log in. I also need the database to store dateandtime stamps, game stats, e.t.c.

I was thinking of using SQLite to implement this and I have already designed the relational database, however, I cannot find a feasible solution to doing so on LibGDX. I have seen forums and posts mentioning the use of interfacing, however, I have researched and tried doing this method for far too long now and to no avail. I have read this article - https://code.google.com/archive/p/libgdx-users/wikis/SQLite.wiki but it doesn't help at all. I have also seen a few third-party extensions for enabling the use of SQLite databases.

This is the link to one I attempted to use which uses interfacing - https://github.com/Inexsoft/libgdx-database-extension

This is the link to one I attempted to use which gives several project files in order to somehow enable the use of a database with LibGDX - https://github.com/Inexsoft/libgdx-database-extension

I am able to implement an interface for Native Functions on a basic level such as opening a website - also from another post I saw on here ([Using SQLite from libGDX on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584959/using-sqlite-from-libgdx-on-android)). However, I have no idea as to how I can develop that example any further to accommodate the use of a database. Please note that I am willing to explore other options in order to store this data, however, it really needs to be in a relational database form due to the nature of my project requirements. It does not have to use SQLite, if there are better alternatives out there.

Any help will be greatly appreciated as I have no other resort left and the project deadline is fast approaching.

Comment: did you evaluate https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Preferences

Comment: @bestwishes I was thinking of using that as a contingency plan but it won't be good enough for my project. I also need to store multiple strings in the same record for a question bank and features such as autoincrement for the user id.

Comment: Typically, android applications would connect to a database through the use of some API on the server the database is running on. So instead of the application manipulating the database itself, it sends HTTP requests to the server and the server code makes the changes. Take a look at https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Networking on how to make these requests.